# Why does AFNetworking load database so slowly in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking

I try to use AFNetworking to get infos from server and set the database in `UITableview`, please look following codes:

```
-(void)requestDB:(NSInteger)typeID {
    NSString *picRequestURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/infos/list/typeid/%ld",API_URL,(long)typeID];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:picRequestURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    op.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];
    [op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         if ([[[responseObject objectForKey:@"status"] stringValue] isEqualToString:@"201"]){
             [self setSquaretableData:[responseObject objectForKey:@"list"]];
             if ([self.SquaretableData count] != 0) {
                 [self.tableview reloadData];
             }
         }
         else {

         }
     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:op];
}
```

in `viewdidload`, I draw a uitableview, and also call `[self requestDB:1]`, but when enter this viewcontroller, all infos in tableview will load so slowly, sometimes, it can't be showed, is my code wrong, is there a right way to do this, thanks.

Comment: You need to reload the table view on the main thread, not a background thread.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm a newer to use AFNetworking, how to reload tableview on main thread, please tech me, many thanks.

Comment: Look at the duplicate question and its answers.